# Give another account full access to all files in one account?

Tags: google-drive, google-account, file-sharing, online-storage

My school gives us Google Drive accounts to do all of our school work in, and teachers frequently "share" files with us through Drive. However, I don't like having two separate accounts — one for school and one for home — so I frequently re-share the files with my home account so that it's all in one place.

Is there a way to do this automatically, where my home account has full access to anything created by or shared with my school account?

Comment: Probably not; the existence of two accounts would be pointless from Google's point of view then.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shared folder -- shared between the two accounts -- and put everything into it.

But that won't automatically handle everything that other people share with one of your accounts.

If your need is to get all newly shared files into the account that you sync locally with GDrive, will it suffice to sync your school account? If not, try writing a Google Apps Script script to automatically tag new docs, putting them into the shared folder.

If your need is to access both accounts without logging out and in frequently, create a second Google Chrome profile for the second account. Then you can keep each profile logged into its associated account at all times. Each profile will open in its own set of Chrome Windows.

Tip: Set a different theme for each profile so you can distinguish them visually.